# How to unshuffle a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**How to unshuffle a pandas data frame**? I accidentally tampered with the original data frame now I want to go back to the original data frame what should I do?

Comment: Youre probably looking for a sort method..... OR just recreate the DF with base data?

Comment: There isn't a way to 'undo' your changes. Depending what you've done you might be able to sort by the index

Comment: restart the kernel? pandas dataframes are in memory objects. If you rewrite your source data/files you'll have to restore it from your database or file system.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.